# How to use Bash extended pattern to match files from the current directory and from one of the subdirectories

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, glob

For example, the following directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── app.js
├── lib
│   └── util.js
└── test
    └── main.js

2 directories, 3 files
```

I would like to match js files from the current directory and `lib/` directory, sort of like:

```
$ ls *.js lib/*.js
app.js  lib/util.js
```

but in a single glob. And this does not do it:

```
ls @(.|lib)/*.js
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if a *glob* would do the intended.  You could use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), however:

```
echo {.,lib}/*.js
```

Comment: This works great. I can even use `ls {*,lib/**/*}.js` with `globstar` on to list all the files recursively from the subdirectory.

Comment: @realguess Yes.  `ls {*,lib/**/*}.js` is equivalent to saying `ls *.js lib/**/*.js`